# Link background image not working on Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm working on this page http://rponcedeleon.com/standalone-delta/ each block (starting with the third block) is supposed to have 3 animated links, so far all of the required functionality is there (works fine in chrome/safari) but the links background images disappear on Firefox. I've noticed that Firefox is adding (inherits) an rgba transparency to all of the links background images, I've tried disabling it but still the images don't show up.

I've tried several fixes but no luck so far, and I don't know what else to do.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The background images are inside a CSS keyframe animation set to infinite, so that it creates the illusion of a pulsating effect switching images like a loop.

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to interpolate between background images is a pretty new proposal so far, and not well supported in browsers. Firefox doesn't implement it yet and the behavior of browsers which animate background-image is non-standard and shouldn't be relied on.